# Two forms of Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: feynman-diagrams

I am confused. I know Feynman Diagrams looks like the ones [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram).
But then I saw these, look in [page 17[1247] of this paper](http://prola.aps.org/pdf/PR/v184/i5/p1231_1).

Any idea?

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall.

Comment: The picture shows all connected Feynman diagrams to a given order with no external legs. A good discussion of them can be found in Peskin and Schroeder, "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory", section 4.4.

Comment: Such Feynman diagrams with no external legs are called [Vacuum bubbles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Vacuum_bubbles).

Comment: OK, so these are normal Feynman Diagrams w/o external legs. But how are the "propagator" represented in such diagrams? Normally it is a curvy internal line (e.g. photon in QED).

Comment: One may always choose different conventions for the shape of the lines for various particle species, can't he?

Comment: Of course. My point was to be sure these are indeed just the 'normal' Feynman diagrams. So in the paper, straight lines actually indicate propagators, right?

Comment: In the first diagram, for example, there is only two loop. Where is the propagator there?

Comment: Yes, there are propagators. See, for instance, the 2-loop vacuum bubble graph page $32$ (Problem 5) of this [paper](http://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~gudrun/teaching/ILC.pdf), and you will see the detailed expression of the graph.